# Copy directory tree and then recursively convert all JPG files in-place

Tags: files, imagemagick

I would like to run the command

```
convert -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 75% 002-02.jpg test
.jpg
```

on all .jpg files in the following subdirectory

```
├── House Altar Data
│   ├── Altar Data 2021 EAST.xlsx
│   ├── Altar Data 2021 NORTH.xlsx
│   ├── Altar Data 2021 SOUTH.xlsx
│   ├── Altar Data 2021 WEST.xlsx
│   ├── Altar data 2021 CENTRAL.xlsx
│   ├── Singkawang Barat (West)
│   │   ├── Pasiran 001 Sam San Ciong Kiun.JPG
│   │   ├── Pasiran 002 Lu San Liuk Ciong.JPG
│   │   ├── Pasiran 003 Hiat Mian Ciong Kiun.JPG
│   │   ├── Pasiran 184 Datuk Bujang Berani.JPG
│   │   ├── Pasiran 185 Sam Bong Ciong Kiun.JPG
│   │   ├── Pasiran 186 Cong San Pak Kung.JPG
│   │   ├── Timur 103 Datuk.JPG
│   │   └── Timur 104 Pak Kung.JPG
│   ├── Singkawang Utara (North)
│   │   ├── Utara 001 Thai Cu Shin Ti.JPG
│   │   ├── Utara 002 Kim San Pak Kung.JPG
│   │   ├── Utara 003 Hian Thian Song Ti.JPG
│   │   ├── Utara 037 Bong Lo Sian Shi.JPG
│   │   ├── Utara 038 Ng Fong Pak Kung.JPG
│   │   └── Utara 039 Ng Fong Pak Kung.JPG
│   ├── TABEL PERBANDINGAN ALTAR 2021.ods
│   ├── altar-central.csv
│   ├── altar-east.csv
│   ├── altar-north.csv
│   ├── altar-south.csv
│   ├── altar-west.csv
└── temple_posters
    ├── 001 DONE Vihara Pusat Kota
    │   ├── 001-01.jpg
    │   ├── 001-02.jpg
    │   ├── 001-03.jpg
    │   ├── 001-04.jpg
    │   ├── 001-05.jpg
    │   └── 001-06.jpg
...
    │   ├── 042-01.jpg
    │   ├── 042-02.jpg
    │   ├── 042-03.jpg
    │   ├── 042-04.jpg
    │   ├── 042-05.jpg
    │   └── 042-06.jpg
    ├── 044 DONE Sam San Ket Bong Sinnam
    │   ├── 044-01.jpg
    │   ├── 044-02.jpg
    │   ├── 044-03.jpg
    │   ├── 044-04.jpg
    │   ├── 044-05.jpg
    │   └── 044-06.jpg
    ├── 045 DONE Phak Lian Shi Kung Sg. Kulor
    │   ├── 045-01.jpg
    │   ├── 045-02.jpg
    │   ├── 045-03.jpg
    │   ├── 045-04.jpg
    │   ├── 045-05.jpg
    │   └── 045-06.jpg
    ├── 046 DONE Cong Thian Shi
    │   ├── 046-01.jpg
    │   ├── 046-02.jpg
    │   ├── 046-03.jpg
    │   ├── 046-04.jpg
    │   ├── 046-05.jpg
    │   └── 046-06.jpg
    ├── 047 DONE Fo San Fut Fab Ki Kiun Kongsisan
    │   ├── 037 DONE Sam Chin Fab Jan Sedau
    │   │   ├── 037-01.jpg
    │   │   ├── 037-02.jpg
    │   │   ├── 037-03.jpg
    │   │   ├── 037-04.jpg
    │   │   ├── 037-05.jpg
    │   │   ├── 037-06.jpg
    │   │   ├── 037-07.jpg
    │   │   └── 037-08.jpg
    │   ├── 047-01.jpg
    │   ├── 047-02.jpg
    │   ├── 047-03.jpg
    │   ├── 047-04.jpg
    │   └── 047-05.jpg
    ├── 048 DONE Thai Pak Kung Gg.3
    │   ├── 048-01.jpg
    │   ├── 048-02.jpg
    │   ├── 048-03.jpg
    │   ├── 048-04.jpg
    │   └── 048-05.jpg
    ├── 049 DONE Tua Pe Kong Jl. Kalimantan
    │   ├── 049-01.jpg
    │   ├── 049-02.jpg
    │   ├── 049-03.jpg
    │   ├── 049-04.jpg
    │   ├── 049-05.jpg
    │   └── 049-06.jpg
    ├── 050 DONE Vihara Buddhayana Roban (Atas)
    │   ├── 050-01.jpg
    │   ├── 050-02.jpg
    │   ├── 050-03.jpg
    │   ├── 050-04.jpg
    │   ├── 050-05.jpg
    │   ├── 050-06.jpg
    │   ├── 050-07.jpg
    │   ├── 050-08.jpg
    │   ├── 050-09.jpg
    │   ├── 050-10.jpg
    │   ├── 050-11.jpg
    │   ├── 050-12.jpg
    │   ├── 050-13.jpg
    │   ├── 050-14.jpg
    │   └── 050-15.jpg
    ├── 051 DONE Vihara Buddhayana Roban (Bawah)
    │   ├── 051-01.jpg
    │   ├── 051-02.jpg
    │   ├── 051-03.jpg
    │   ├── 051-04.jpg
    │   ├── 051-05.jpg
    │   ├── 051-06.jpg
    │   └── 051-07.jpg
    ├── 052 DONE Kwan Im Pajintan
    │   ├── 052-01.jpg
    │   ├── 052-02.jpg
    │   ├── 052-03.jpg
    │   ├── 052-04.jpg
    │   ├── 052-05.jpg
    │   ├── 052-06.jpg
    │   ├── 052-07.jpg
    │   └── 052-08.jpg
    ├── 053 DONE Sui Tet Sen Kiun Kulor
    │   ├── 053-01.jpg
    │   ├── 053-02.jpg
    │   ├── 053-03.jpg
    │   ├── 053-04.jpg
    │   └── 053-05.jpg
    ├── DAFTAR DEWA-DEWI with DESCRIPTION UPDATE.xlsx
    └── Map of Singkawang with Mandarin.jpg
```

I would like to replicate the file structure and image names;

I have no idea where to start - would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Relevant: [Understanding the `-exec` option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389705/108618)

Comment: Please expand on "replicate the file structure and image names": does that mean creating a copy of the directory tree some place else and processing the duplicate files or does it mean working on the original files and overwriting them?

Comment: The former - creating a copy somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
find ./dir -iname '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
    echo convert -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 \
        -quality 75% "$1" "$1.temp" && mv "$1.temp" "$1"
' -- {} \;
```

Remove `echo` statement if the output looks good for you.

The original files are overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You could recursively copy that directory with `rsync` (e.g. to `backup`):

```
rsync -av /path/to/my_subdir /path/to/backup/
```

To copy only `JPG` files and ignore other files as well as empty directories you would instead run:

```
rsync -avm --include='*.[jJ][pP][gG]' --include='*/' --exclude='*' /path/to/your/subdir /path/to/backup/
```

You would then act on the duplicates with `mogrify` (also part of `imagemagick`) which can batch-convert images in-place:

```
find /path/to/backup/my_subdir -name '*.[jJ][pP][gG]' -exec \
mogrify -strip -interlace Plane -gaussian-blur 0.05 -quality 75% {} +
```